# Efficient way of using if loop or switch case with qt widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I have a form where in a text edit the user gives the input integer with a maximum value of 3, according to this i have to show the number of push buttons. In designer i have created 3 push buttons with layout, and according to the input i used switch case and hide the button. Is there any other efficient way to create the widgets according to the user input. In my form contsrutor:

```
switch(input)
{
case1:
button2->setvisible(false);
button3->setvisible(false); // so only one btn is visible
case 2:
button3->setvisible(false); // so only btn 1 nd 2 are visible
case 3:
// do nothing.
}
```

The above seems to be simple, but i have few frames, line edits and radio btns, so the code is long and i think it is not efficient. Please suggest me some other alternative. I have used disabling whole frame, this also works but looking for some other options or may be use of if conditions in a better way. 
Is it a better to create them dynamically??Thank you

Comment: Don't forget your `break;`s or execution will fall through the next `case`.

Comment: Don't worry about `switch` performance... If this is not about performance but 'nice looking code', what about using `setvisible(condition_here)` ?

Comment: @Gizmo: I did not understand.

Comment: @vinayrajputh `button2->setvisible(input != 1);` for example, no using switch cases. Also look at @Tomaz's answer.

Comment: Are you trying to show the buttons from `0` to `input` and hide the rest of the buttons?

Comment: yes, supoose i have three buttons defined using designer, and when user gives an input of one, then i hide two button to show only one button. And as i am using in Qwizard pages i need to use these widget pointers in many functions so i have created statically rather than writing hand written and also has lot of layouts, frames and spacer items.

Comment: @kubaOber: I think that same code is repeated and with more widgets it is really worse. and next is when this is the case should i go with dynamic creation? Normally in the above case what would be the best way to create a gui?

Comment: *it is really worse* It's worse **how**? Don't ask about solutions before you clearly state why do you think you have a problem, and what sort of solutions you're looking for. Otherwise this question is off-topic due to being too broad.

Comment: @KubaOber:  Worsein the sense repetitive line of codes, as i have started recently, i would want to know the best approach for this kind of application, where there is need of few dynamic multiple widgets depending upon the user input value , so that in future if someone wants to expand the implementation he should not have much problem (in my case he would see static elements on the form and i disable and enable them). so was confused whether to go with dynamic creation and if not how could i implement the visibility enabling and disabling..

Comment: OK, so you're trying to reduce the amount of code, presumably to make it easier to maintain (otherwise it'd be quite pointless). Please provide a screenshot that demonstrates **exactly** the setup of the widgets, so that we can infer the tree structure involved.

Answer (score 1):

if you know the number of push buttons that you have, and the input is an integer, then it should be easy:

```
 QList<QPushButton*> buttons = { ui->btn1, ui->btn2... } // all your buttons here.
 for(int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    buttons[i]->setVisible(true);
 for(int i = input; i < buttons.size(); i++) 
    buttons[i]->setVisible(false);
```

first make sure that all buttons untill 'input' are visible, then hide all the buttons from 'input' to the end of the list.

Comment: from his simple example, it looks like it.

Comment: I have used the above method too. The problem is i have lot of widgets, somewhere around 25. :( As i have used layouts, frames and spacers, i was wondering should i go for dynamic i.e. coding rather than using designer.

Comment: @vinayrajputh But in your question the only widgets that change are those three pushbuttons, correct?

Comment: @mrg95 , Yes i have simplified to explain it. But in my code, there are still lot of widgets.